# Trigger a batch file when a user choose "Switch User" in windows

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, task-scheduler

I save log in/out details of all the users to a text file through a `.bat` file, which is executed by `Task Scheduler` (*on workstation-lock/unlock*)/ `gpedit.msc` (*on user logout/login*).

I want to run the same or any `.bat`file when *Switch User* is chosen instead of log out/ workstation lock after `CTRL+ALT+DEL`.
The `.bat` file looks like

```
echo Logoff: %date% %time:~0,5% %UserName% >> c:\Logs\History.txt
```

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best choice is to configure [Advanced security audit policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772712%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and windows will register for you events about:

1. [User logon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941635%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
2. [Workstation lock/unlock](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772658%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
3. [User logout](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941621%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

and many others that may be useful to you.

After it you will be able to [analyze](http://www.logalyze.com/), [collect](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/centralizing-windows-logs/) and generally to do with these logs everything that you see fit.

If you want something to run, then you can always set up a task scheduler that runs in the registration of a certain event in the Windows event log:
when configurings scheduled task trigger you has can select to start task *"when a specific event is logged"*. Simply select *Security* log and *4779* eventid.

Comment: I agree. But I am skeptical about 'switch user' being logged. Consider a scenario : User A logs in > **A** presses CTRL+ALT+DEL> **A** chooses `switch user` and leaves the system> User **B** logs in. In this case **A**'s login time is logged and **B**'s login time is logged. But, no trace of **A** leaving the system (he never signed off). Correct me if I am missing something here.

Comment: If Windows considers `switch user` to be "_Workstation Lock_" event, then the lock/unlock script should also be executed right ( which I trigger through task scheduler ) ?

Comment: Sorry - misled - when user  chooses `switch user` occurs  event **4779** *"A session was disconnected from a Window Station."* In any case, the audit log contains all events that reflect the changes the user's session.

Comment: Yeah, logs are maintained. But was wondering, will I be able to run a `.bat` on `switch user`?

Comment: I added in my answer the information how to set up task launch by event.